# I am scraping the websites which has javascript enabled and can't scrape a single content

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
    import time
    import sys
    
    url = 'https://www.researchgate.net/search.Search.html?type=researcher&query=islamia%20college%20peshawar'
    chrome_driver_path = '/home/danish-khan/webscraping/rgcrawler2/chromedriver'
    
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
      executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
    )
    
    driver.get(url)
    
    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rgw3_5fb33547bc20c"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/a')
    print(name)'
```

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "resgt3.py", line 26, in <module>
    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rgw3_5fb33547bc20c"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/a')
  File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="rgw3_5fb33547bc20c"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/a"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

Comment: I think that you should tell selenium to wait some time before trying to extract that element. Maybe using something like  ```WebDriverWait```, you could specify a timeout.

Comment: What element did you want to grab?

Comment: I want to get the profile information of all users(researchers)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable this line

`chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')`

and spawn a browser. This way, it will load the full javascript, just like a normal browser for you.

If the javascript takes too long to load, try adding a `sleep(10)` or a `wait` for the element that you can use as an anchor to test if the js is fully loaded.

---

**Edit:**

I used Chrome dev tools and manually tried to locate the element using your xpath in the loaded webpage for [your url](https://www.researchgate.net/search/researcher?q=islamia%2Bcollege%2Bpeshawar), and found out your xpath does not actually work, maybe try to fix your xpath in the dev tools first.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is not about loading time or javascript. Using chrome devtool we can see that the xpath you are using to locate your element is not valid. That's because the website you are trying to scrape uses elements whose ids changes when the page is refreshed.

A lot of websites use this method to prevent automation.
There are multiple options that you can use to counter this problem.
You can learn about those in [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/18358).
To summarise, you could try to find other attributes like classes or style. You can also use xpath functions such as `contains()` or `start-with()` or even sometimes the full (absolute) xpath.